# Cloud and Datacenter

Tags: architecture, cloud

We are in the process of design a new application which based on a hybrid cloud architecture. We want to keep the data center centralized and managed in-house. And the appserver could be hosted by one of the service providers like EC2 Amazon.
I am looking some best practice around data connection between the cloud and datacenter and how secure it.
~Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That's going to create a pretty slow application. I'd *strongly* recommend having your DB and App servers on the same network.

But if you really can't, then just secure it as you would any public-facing server:

1. Lock down to IPs
2. Make sure the password is secure
3. Potentially change the default port to something non-standard